# Way to compare DOM/all properties before and after an event?

Tags: javascript, dom, diff, dump

I am having an issue where when I repeat a 3dtransform multiple times it starts to degrade performance in strange ways.

What I want to know is -- is there some way to dump the entirety of the pages DOM and all properties before and after so that I can run a diff and see what's being left behind? I know I can copy out the html from the web inspector, but is there any way to dump all the elements and all their properties? I know this would be long, but hopefully the diff would be comparatively short once run.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MutationObserver on the document object to get the architecture/properties/attributes changes of the dom beginning the observation at a given moment.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver
http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers